# Using orWhere with eloquent

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I have as tables: courriers(courrier_id, repondre ..) and reponses(reponse_id, structure, courrier_id) which are linked by a one-to-many relation
(1 courrier can have several reponses)
I want to find the courriers where courriers.repondre = 1 and which have no reponses Or the courriers which have reponses and reponses.structure <> 'INFO'
How could I do this with Eloquent
I'm trying:

```php
$courriers = Courrier::where('repondre', '=', 1)
    ->doesntHave('reponses')
    ->orWhere('reponses.structure', '<>', 'DMO')
    ->get();
```

The condition (repondre,'=','1') must be verified in the two cases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First two conditions must be grouped together for your query to work.

```php
Courrier::where('repondre', 1)
    ->where(function ($query) {
        $query->doesntHave('responses')
              ->orWhereHas('responses', function ($query) {
                  $query->where('structure', '<>', 'DMD');
              });
    })
    ->get()
```

Comment: The condition (repondre,'=','1') must be verified in the two cases

Comment: I'll edit my answer. Basically move the where('repondre', 1) out of the where closure and move the orWhereHas inside.